# Use a virtual machines network adapter as hosts default network adapter

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm

Objective: Use a virtual machine network adapter as host's default network adapter.

I am looking for advice on how to set this up correctly. The purpose is to have my wireless interface (which requires non-free firmware) in a virtual machine and to have the host use this virtual machine as the gateway and firewall for all connections.

I am using Debian Sid without contrib or non-free software. I successfully have IPFire running in a virtual machine, using KVM, with my wireless adapter attached using PCI Passthrough, and attached to the red interface. IPFire recognizes my adapter fine, so no problems there.

The IPFire machine on the green interface is set to 192.168.0.1, and I have enabled the DHCP server on IPFire and green interface. My current trouble is where I want my host system to connect to the green interface (which is in the virtual machine, inside the host), but I am not sure how to achieve this (and Google does not turn up much). I'm not entirely sure on how I am supposed to set up KVM's virtual networks. I can see the virtual networks on the host system, such as virbr0, but they also seem to be allocating addresses not specified in IPFire.

In a sense, I wish to create a virtual Ethernet connection which is connected to the green interface on the IPFire virtual machine, and the host system would get its network address from the DHCP server on the IPFire virtual machine.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Update:
ifconfig of host:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:de:f1:dd:95:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3113  bytes 3331853 (3.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2272  bytes 310690 (303.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe2500000-e2520000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 216  bytes 17124 (16.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 216  bytes 17124 (16.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:86:56:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ip route of host:

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr1 scope link metric 1000 linkdown
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the output of `ifconfig` and `ip route` (on your host) to your question?